# Change Main Camera lookAt on game object click

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having some trouble changing the camera's lookAt target.  Right now I have this script "Zoomer" attached to the Main Camera, which creates a "target" variable that can be changed in the inspector:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Zoomer : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform target;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    transform.LookAt (target);
}
}
```

However, I have another script "Forge_Scene" attached to a game object "Smith" and when I click on it, I want to be able to change the "target" variable to "Smith", so the camera focuses on the game object.  How would I do this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe add a string array of every component you want your camera to follow, and then just use getcomponent to get it by name?

Comment: @Paul a decent solution, but perhaps consider wrapping these items in an Enum in case you go around renaming things, this would mean only a single place to change if you did rename an object. Another solution might be to fire a ray from the mouse and then grab the gameobject that it intersects and focus on that.